# Populating a hidden input with a value from data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet of my code here. I'm fairly new to Javascript and I for the life of me can't figure this out. So what happens is the bottom part of the code pulls in data and put its into a table. What I want to do is when I click the button in the last column it takes the item.ReviewId and automatically populates a hidden input in a modal to match the item that the person is reviewing. Any help would be appreciated. When I click it it automatically populates with the last number on the list. For example if there are 3 items, 20,21,22 and I click the first one and it populates with 22.

```
var success = function (result) {          

        $.each(result.Items, function (index, item) {            

            $('#reviewresults').dataTable().fnAddData([razorHelpers.formatDate(item.DateVisited), item.clientProfile.CompanyName, razorHelpers.formatCurrency(item.AmountSpent), item.ReviewId, '<button class="btn btn-blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="View" id="review">Review This Transaction <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>']);

            console.log(item.ReviewId)

            $("#review").on("click", function () {
                test(item.ReviewId)
            });

            function test(number) {
                $("#reviewinput").val(number);
            }

        });

    };     

    ClientOpenReviewService.ListReviewsByConsumer(razorStorage.ExtractSessionData('userId'), 0, 0).done(success);
```

Comment: You might want to define your `test` function outside the `$.each`.

Comment: can you show  jsfiddle of it?

Comment: The reason why you're always getting the last one is because you have an `each` statement. The last item will always set the value of the hidden input. Is there a reason why you have to loop instead of just using the right `item`?

Comment: Also, you have to fix your problem of having the same `id` for a lot of elements because of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Without really understanding your code I'm going to attempt to rewrite it to the best of my knowledge:

```
function test(number) {
  $("#reviewinput").val(number);
}

var success = function (result) {
  $.each(result.Items, function(index, item) {
    $('#reviewresults').dataTable().fnAddData(
      [razorHelpers.formatDate(item.DateVisited),
      item.clientProfile.CompanyName,
      razorHelpers.formatCurrency(item.AmountSpent),
      item.ReviewId,
      '<button data-review="'+item.ReviewId+'" class="btn btn-blue review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="View" id="review-'+item.ReviewId+'">Review This Transaction <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>'
      ]
    );

    console.log(item.ReviewId)
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  ClientOpenReviewService.ListReviewsByConsumer(razorStorage.ExtractSessionData('userId'), 0, 0).done(success);

  $(".review").on("click", function() {
    test($(this).data('review'));
  });
});
```

Comment: one thing that is throwing me off is that the 'item.ReviewId' is defined in the .each statement

Comment: @JosephNylund Ah I see, I will have to edit my answer. But first, is `success` the function that gets the value of `item.ReviewId`?

Comment: Yes I believe so. As soon as I move it anywhere outside of the `.each` statement it becomes undefined

Comment: @JosephNylund That makes sense. Is there a reason why you want to loop instead of using the right `item`?

Comment: Well it's pulling in JSON data. So the numbers aren't set and could go on forever.

Comment: @JosephNylund I think I understand your situation now. I've updated my answer. You should take note of how I'm adding the `button` element with `data-review` and just using that for when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through result.Items and on each iteration you are creating a click listener

> $("#review").on("click", function (){})

This listener is being appended onto **#review** (which may be a button or div). So you are ending up with a #review element that has a number of listeners attached.

It is probably only showing the ***LAST*** element because all the listeners are being executed sequentially after the #review element has been clicked.

To illustrate I wrote this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="review">
OK

</div>

<script>

    result = {};
    result.Items = [
        {
            ReviewId:1
        },
        {
            ReviewId:2
        },
        {
            ReviewId:3
        },
        {
            ReviewId:4
        }];


    $.each(result.Items, function (index, item) {

        $("div").on("click", function () {

            test(item.ReviewId)
        });

        function test(number) {

            alert(number)

            $("#reviewinput").val(number);
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see how the click event creates 4 alert boxes, and the last alert box is the last number from the array.

I think what you want is a number of elements #review_1 #review_2 etc for your different columns. You need to rethink your design i think.